# noqa does not suppress the warning for flake8

Tags: flycheck, warning

The example warning I am getting is `Item "None" of "Optional[IO[bytes]]" has no attribute "close"]`, as making the line bold and red. This usually occurs if Python cannot detect the type or its function.

The way I imported: `from subprocess import PIPE, STDOUT, CalledProcessError, Popen, check_output`

---

[image]

- Using `# NOQA`, `# flake8: noqa` did not help, represented as `flycheck-warning'`.

I still want to see the warning for unused imports but if I use `# noqa` I want them to go away.

---

Setup file, complete section for flycheck is here: https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/e8713d871696538bf59a0c0245a878ec :

```
(use-package flycheck-pycheckers
  :after flycheck
  :ensure t
  :init
  (with-eval-after-load 'flycheck
    (add-hook 'flycheck-mode-hook #'flycheck-pycheckers-setup)
    )
  (setq flycheck-pycheckers-checkers
    '(
      mypy3
      pyflakes
      )
    )
  )
```

---

In my configuraiton I believe `flake8` is enabled.

```
Elpy Configuration

Emacs.............: 26.3
Elpy..............: 1.34.0
Virtualenv........: venv (/home/alper/venv)
Interactive Python: python3 3.7.5 (/home/alper/venv/bin/python3)
RPC virtualenv....: rpc-venv (/home/alper/.emacs.d/elpy/rpc-venv)
 Python...........: python 3.7.5 (/home/alper/.emacs.d/elpy/rpc-venv/bin/python)
 Jedi.............: 0.17.2
 Rope.............: 0.16.0
 Autopep8.........: 1.5.4
 Yapf.............: 0.30.0
 Black............: 20.8b1
Syntax checker....: flake8 (/home/alper/.local/bin/flake8)
```

---

Update:

Output of `flycheck-verify-setup`:

```
Syntax checkers for buffer Driver.py in python-mode:

First checker to run:

  python-flake8
    - may enable:         yes
    - executable:         Found at /Users/alper/venv/bin/python3
    - configuration file: Not found
    - `flake8' module:    Found at "/Users/alper/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flake8/__init__.py"
    - next checkers:      python-mypy, python-pylint

Checkers that may run as part of the first checker's chain:

  python-pylint
    - may enable:         yes
    - executable:         Found at /Users/alper/venv/bin/pylint
    - configuration file: Found at "/Users/alper/.pylintrc"
    - next checkers:      python-mypy

  python-mypy
    - may enable:         yes
    - executable:         Found at /Users/alper/venv/bin/mypy
    - configuration file: Found at "/Users/alper/eBlocBroker/setup.cfg"

Checkers that could run if selected:

  python-pycompile  select
    - may enable:    yes
    - executable:    Found at /Users/alper/venv/bin/python3
    - next checkers: python-mypy

Checkers that are compatible with this mode, but will not run until properly configured:

  python-pyright (automatically disabled) reset
    - may enable: no
    - executable: Not found

Flycheck Mode is enabled.  Use C-u C-c ! x to enable disabled checkers.

--------------------

Flycheck version: 32snapshot (package: 20201023.1716)
Emacs version:    26.3
System:           x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Window system:    nil
```

---

Output of `M-x -> describe-variable` AND `flycheck-checkers`:

```
flycheck-checkers is a variable defined in ‘flycheck.el’.
Its value is
(python-pycheckers solium-checker solidity-checker ada-gnat asciidoctor asciidoc awk-gawk bazel-buildifier
c/c++-clang c/c++-gcc c/c++-cppcheck cfengine chef-foodcritic coffee coffee-coffeelint coq css-csslint
css-stylelint cuda-nvcc cwl d-dmd dockerfile-hadolint elixir-credo emacs-lisp emacs-lisp-checkdoc ember-template
erlang-rebar3 erlang eruby-erubis eruby-ruumba fortran-gfortran go-gofmt go-golint go-vet go-build go-test
go-errcheck go-unconvert go-staticcheck groovy haml handlebars haskell-stack-ghc haskell-ghc haskell-hlint
html-tidy javascript-eslint javascript-jshint javascript-standard json-jsonlint json-python-json json-jq jsonnet
less less-stylelint llvm-llc lua-luacheck lua markdown-markdownlint-cli markdown-mdl nix nix-linter opam perl
perl-perlcritic php php-phpmd php-phpcs processing proselint protobuf-protoc protobuf-prototool pug puppet-parser
puppet-lint python-flake8 python-pylint python-pycompile python-pyright python-mypy r-lintr racket rpm-rpmlint
rst-sphinx rst ruby-rubocop ruby-standard ruby-reek ruby-rubylint ruby ruby-jruby rust-cargo rust rust-clippy
scala scala-scalastyle scheme-chicken scss-lint scss-stylelint sass/scss-sass-lint sass scss sh-bash
sh-posix-dash sh-posix-bash sh-zsh sh-shellcheck slim slim-lint sql-sqlint systemd-analyze tcl-nagelfar terraform
terraform-tflint tex-chktex tex-lacheck texinfo textlint typescript-tslint verilog-verilator vhdl-ghdl
xml-xmlstarlet xml-xmllint yaml-jsyaml yaml-ruby yaml-yamllint)
Original value was
(ada-gnat asciidoctor asciidoc awk-gawk bazel-buildifier c/c++-clang c/c++-gcc c/c++-cppcheck cfengine
chef-foodcritic coffee coffee-coffeelint coq css-csslint css-stylelint cuda-nvcc cwl d-dmd dockerfile-hadolint
elixir-credo emacs-lisp emacs-lisp-checkdoc ember-template erlang-rebar3 erlang eruby-erubis eruby-ruumba
fortran-gfortran go-gofmt go-golint go-vet go-build go-test go-errcheck go-unconvert go-staticcheck groovy haml
handlebars haskell-stack-ghc haskell-ghc haskell-hlint html-tidy javascript-eslint javascript-jshint
javascript-standard json-jsonlint json-python-json json-jq jsonnet less less-stylelint llvm-llc lua-luacheck lua
markdown-markdownlint-cli markdown-mdl nix nix-linter opam perl perl-perlcritic php php-phpmd php-phpcs
processing proselint protobuf-protoc protobuf-prototool pug puppet-parser puppet-lint python-flake8 python-pylint
python-pycompile python-pyright python-mypy r-lintr racket rpm-rpmlint rst-sphinx rst ruby-rubocop ruby-standard
ruby-reek ruby-rubylint ruby ruby-jruby rust-cargo rust rust-clippy scala scala-scalastyle scheme-chicken
scss-lint scss-stylelint sass/scss-sass-lint sass scss sh-bash sh-posix-dash sh-posix-bash sh-zsh sh-shellcheck
slim slim-lint sql-sqlint systemd-analyze tcl-nagelfar terraform terraform-tflint tex-chktex tex-lacheck texinfo
textlint typescript-tslint verilog-verilator vhdl-ghdl xml-xmlstarlet xml-xmllint yaml-jsyaml yaml-ruby
yaml-yamllint)
```

Comment: Pyflakes doesn't appear to support the `# NOQA` (or similar) syntax for ignoring errors. See (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033727/how-do-i-get-pyflakes-to-ignore-a-statement) and (https://github.com/PyCQA/pyflakes/issues/431). You likely want to use `flake8` instead of `pyflakes` as a syntax checker, which will allow your `# NOQA` comments to work again.

Comment: Hm as I understand I have to run `pyflakes` under `flake8`. I think I am already using `flake8` so I just remove `pyflakes` from `.emacs` and pip packages should resolve it

Comment: @D.Gillis not sure but I still have the same error even `pyflakes ` is not defined in my `.emacs` file and seems like flake8 is enables: `Syntax checker....: flake8 (/home/user/.local/bin/flake8)`

Comment: I think the warning you are getting is coming from some kind of static analyzer (such as jedi or mypy) other than flake8, which would explain why `# NOQA` doesn't work here. Unless it has changed recently, flake8 does not look at types, so it wouldn't be able to return a warning about an `AttributeError`. If the error is from mypy, adding the comment `# type: ignore` may work (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49220022/). If it does not work, can you provide the values of `elpy-syntax-checker`,`python-check-command`, and `python-flymake-command` in the buffer where this occurs?

Comment: Thanks `# type: ignore` works on my end.For `python-check-command` I am having `/home/alper/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages is in the MYPYPATH. Please remove it.`

Comment: I wasn't able to run `elpy-syntax-checker` and `python-flymake-command` in the `M-x`; seems like they do not exist

Comment: It seems like your flycheck is running a Mypy checker. I think this was done outside of Elpy, since I don't believe Elpy directly supports running more than one checker. I believe I have solved your problem, but I think it would be good to provide some more details to help other users who may find this question. Can you run the command `flycheck-verify-setup` and write the enabled checkers into your question? I expect that `python-mypy` will be enabled. If it is not, however, please provide the value of the variable `flycheck-checkers`.

Comment: @D.Gillis I updated my questions with output of `flycheck-verify-setup` but I was able to get value for `flycheck-checkers` from `describe-variable`; please let me know if you require any more information

Comment: You may have other errors in your code, beside unused imports - try to run flake8 in terminal with a command such as: ```flake8 --isolated --output-file yourfile.log yourfile.py``` and then add error numbers to your #noqa. Also, you can double-check with pylint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some problem(s) in your code - you did not show how you imported the subprocess module - my guess is you just written `import subprocess`, which is not what you want. Instead use `from subprocess import popen, PIPE`.

The reason is if you do not import PIPE, stdout is not declared/recognised, so `p1.stdout.close()` does not exist; this also explains the message `Item "None" of "Optional[IO[bytes]]" has no attribute "close"`.

Comment: I have tried `from subprocess import popen, PIPE` but still facing with the same error message. https://github.com/jacktasia/dumb-jump can jump into right `close()` function but seems like its not detected by the `flake8`

Comment: Try from command line my suggestion posted on Dec 11'20 in comments on your question and see the result. BTW, seems to me flake8 is not inserted in flycheck-pycheckers-checkers. Take into account the #noqa must be completed with error numbers, there are many cases when it is not recognised; there is also a flake8-noqa package installable with pip which checks for correct #noqa. One last word: if still problems with this, a wise decision is to install lsp + server python-language-server (with pip).

Comment: `# type: ignore` works on my end but still `# noqa` does not with all the suggestions I tried :-(